# PHP loaded via Ajax is not being executed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

On my main page (lets call it `index`) I have a div called `#main` and I am updating its contents using JQuery and PHP when one of the links in the navigation menu is clicked with a file (lets called it `NEWPAGE`). The issue I am having is any PHP loaded this way won't be executed.

So, for example, when one of the links is clicked on `index`, my JQuery script will loaded the contents of `NEWPAGE` into `#main`.

Any and all HTML content in `NEWPAGE` loads perfectly fine but PHP content does not.

E.g. if the contents of `NEWPAGE` was: `<p>Hello stackoverflow</p>`, I would see that. But if the contents were:

```
<p><?php
echo "Hello stackoverflow";
?><p>
```

I would end up seeing nothing.

How do I remedy this?

P.S. I should I am really new to PHP and Javascript.

Comment: PHP can only run on the server. You can't run it *after* it's been downloaded.

Comment: Can you post the code doing your Ajax call or the PHP code it's calling?  If the PHP isn't being executed it's probably because your webserver doesn't realize it's PHP.  Maybe check that the file extension on the called file is PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file you call `NEWPAGE`, what actually is its filename? It will probably need to end `.php` for your server to know that any PHP code that contents should be interpreted before a result is sent. Otherwise your server will simply send the conents of the file as though it were plain text or HTML. Try using whatever DOM inspection is built in to your web browser to look for the `main` div and see if incontains uninterpreted  PHP.

Search for 'yourbrowsername devloper tools` and look for pages like these for instructions of how to inspect the elements on your webpage:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Tools_Toolbox

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ie/bg182326(v=vs.85)

Assuming you have tested you code with the `<p>Hello stackoverflow</p>` example you provided, I think filename not being `NEWPAGE.php` is your problem.

Comment: So the file I am calling `NEWPAGE` is actually called newpage.php

Edit: I can't get the formatting right in this comment box so I have linked it externally.

The code I am using it call is: 
JS: http://pastebin.com/6biAUcFc
PHP: http://pastebin.com/rGiT8S7K

Comment: I see your problem. Good work on not simply letting that PHP script use `get_file_contents` on any thing it's asked for btw. It still creates a potential security hazard though. I would would ditch it completely and use JS to detect if the page ajax gives you is your sites 404 page. If you want to keep using `load_page.php` to handle your ajax request you will need to use `include` instead of `get_file_contents` and some more rigorous checking of the page being requested. If memory serves me a hacker could add `../` to beginning of the file name to access pages out side the `pages` directory.

Comment: Just to clarify, should I use the JS to load the `newpage` aswell or just for the 404 checking?

Comment: Yeah, if you ditch `load_page.php` change your ajax call like this `$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'pages/'+url,
                dataType: "html",
                success: function(msg){
                       
                        if(parseInt(msg)!=0)
                        {
                                $('#main').html(msg);
                                //$('#loading').css('visibility','hidden');
                        }
                }
               
        });

Comment: If your 404 page is not suitable to display (maybe it repeats the menus or results in a page within a page) add something unique to the 404 page (maybe a string of nonsense characters hidden in an HTML comment) and add a line to the success function that checks if `msg` contains that special something and display `"Page not found"` instead of `msg`

Comment: I can't upvote because I don't have the required reputation but this works perfectly. I will stick to the JS as suggested. Thank you.

Comment: Cheers accepting my answer gave me enough rep to up vote your question. Lets hope it helps someone else some day.